# How to call useDispatch in a callback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I got a React component which is trying to get some data, and is calling an `onSuccess(result)` call back upon a successful retrieval of data.

I need to save the data to redux. I created custom hooks which are using `useDispatch`, and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<MyComponent onSuccess = {res => myCustomHook(res)} />
```

but I get an error because an hook can not be called inside a callback.

I know that hooks can only be called at the top level of a functional component.. So how can I achieve what I need?

The custom hook:

```
    export function useSaveData(type, response)
  {
    if(!type|| !response)
    {
      throw new Error("got wrong parameters for useSaveData");
    }
    let obj= {
      myData1: response.data1,
      myData2: response.data2
    };
    sessionStorage.setItem(type, JSON.stringify(obj));
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(actionCreator.addAction(type, obj));
  }
```

Comment: why did you create a custom hook? you could just dispatch your action in "onSuccess". Also: useSelector will automatically update as soon as your redux state updates

Comment: You should dispatch the data in `MyComponent`. If parent class needs to be aware of the data, yield from its child than, this data could be passed to the parent in props.

Comment: @sardok The child collects the data and then needs to run a callback upon success

Comment: Can you post `myCustomHook` briefly?

Comment: @sardok I have edited with the custom hook

Comment: you don't need to create custom hook, you can simply pass dispatch to your onSuccess callback.

Comment: @eramit2010 I got some more logic besides only using dispatch. Also, I need the code to be reused

Comment: then you can return a function from your custom hook which can be used when you need to fire onSuccess as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent component could pass dispatcher to `useSaveData` as follows.

```
    export const useSaveData = (dispatch) => (type, response) =>
  {
    if(!type|| !response)
    {
      throw new Error("got wrong parameters for useSaveData");
    }
    let obj= {
      myData1: response.data1,
      myData2: response.data2
    };
    sessionStorage.setItem(type, JSON.stringify(obj));
    dispatch(actionCreator.addAction(type, obj));
  }
```

And parent component becomes;

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const myCustomHook = useSaveData(dispatch);
    return <MyComponent onSuccess = {res => myCustomHook(ACTION_TYPE, res)} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom hook should return a function which can be passed as callback.

```
useMyCustomHook = () => {
  // your hook
  const onSuccess = () => {
    // save data here
  }
  return { onSuccess };
}
```

In your component.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
   const { onSuccess } = useMyCustomHook();
   // your component code, you have onSuccess which can be bind with button or form as per your requirement.
}
```

---

Edit after seeing your custom hook.

You don't need to create custom hook here. you can simply pass dispatch to your callback.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
<MyComponent onSuccess={res => onSuccess(res, dispatch)} />
```

create onSucces function.

```
export function onSuccess(type, response, dispatch)
  {
    if(!type|| !response)
    {
      throw new Error("got wrong parameters for useSaveData");
    }
    let obj= {
      myData1: response.data1,
      myData2: response.data2
    };
    sessionStorage.setItem(type, JSON.stringify(obj));
    dispatch(actionCreator.addAction(type, obj));
  }
```

Comment: And how do I pass it to the component?

Answer (score 0):

`useDispatch` is a React Redux hook, and can not be directly used anywhere outside of the functional component's body. You would not be allowed to even directly use it within another plain javascript function, even if it was getting invoked from the functional component's body. So, to use the `useDispatch` hook elsewhere, a const can be declared out of the `useDispatch` hook.Please note that, this should only happen from within your functional component like below:

```
export default function MyComponent {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
......
}
```

Now, this const dispatch can be passed around anywhere else, including a call back. Within your call back, you may access the passed `dispatch` argument and invoke redux APIs on it, like below:

```
export function useSaveData(type, response, dispatch)
  {
    if(!type|| !response)
    {
      throw new Error("got wrong parameters for useSaveData");
    }
    let obj= {
      myData1: response.data1,
      myData2: response.data2
    };
    sessionStorage.setItem(type, JSON.stringify(obj));
    dispatch(actionCreator.addAction(type, obj));
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to answer this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748180/should-i-use-useselector-instead-of-mapstatetoprops

Comment: @YonatanNir - Will have a look once I get some time.