# How to call useSelector inside callback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

This is a follow up question to this question:

[How to call useDispatch in a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456816/how-to-call-usedispatch-in-a-callback)

I got a React component which needs to receive information from redux in its props. The information is taken using a custom hook.

This is the custom hook:

```
  export function useGetData(selectorFunc)
  {
    return type =>
    {
      if(!type)
      {
        throw new Error("got a wrong type");
      }
      let myData = selectorFunc(state => 
      {
        let res = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(type));
        if(!res )
        {
          res = state.myReducer.myMap.get(type);
        }
        return res;
      });
      return myData;
    }
  }
```

Based on the answer for the linked question, I tried doing something like this:

```
function Compo(props)
{
   const getDataFunc = useGetData(useSelector);
   return <MyComponent dataNeeded = { getDataFunc(NeededType).dataNeeded } />
}
```

but I get an error because an hook can not be called inside a callback.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the selector, just use it.

Also, according to your logic, you should parse the storage key outside the selector.

```
export function useDataFunc() {
  const myData = useSelector(state => myReducer.myMap);

  const getDataFunc = type => {
    const resByData = myData.get(type);
    try {
      // JSON.parse can throw an error!
      const res = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(type));
    } catch (e) {
      return resByData;
    }
    return res ? res : resByData;
  };
  return getDataFunc;
}

function Compo(props) {
  const getDataFunc = useDataFunc();
  return <MyComponent dataNeeded={getDataFunc(NeededType).dataNeeded} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like,

```
const myData = useSelector(state => state.myReducer.myMap);
```