# Should I use useselector/useDispatch instead of mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

When creating a React app, if I use the hook `useSelector`, I need to adhere to the hooks invoking rules (Only call it from the top level of a functional component). If I use the `mapStateToProps`, I get the state in the props and I can use it anywhere without any issues... Same issue for `useDispatch`

What are the benefits of using the hook besides saving lines of code compared to `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Have you read this: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: Yes and it does not answer the question of benefits

Comment: General hooks motivations ( https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation ) does? multiple useSelector, more granular? more readable 'consuming'

Comment: @xadm no, since I still can't use the redux state everywhere with hooks like I can with mapstatetoprops

Comment: Both are fully valid concepts. However, for me personally using hooks allows for a more clear distinction of props coming in the component from a parent, and the ones that component consumes from the state, using a selector.

Comment: Maybe your components are too complex, needs deeper decomposition (in the same file)? Show an example where it is a problem

Comment: A simple example would be trying to access the state of a store inside a callback function.. you can't do that with useSelector while you do can with state inside the props

Comment: You should be able to use data/value/ref returned by `useSelector()` inside callback, you can't call `useSelector()` in other context than "render flow" of functional components - general "rules of hooks"

Comment: That's exactly the point.. the rules of hooks make it very hard to use that specific hook. You still need to somehow access a *changing* value from the state inside callbacks..

Comment: Since no one knows how to answer, it seems like the best answer is that you should NOT be using useselector when you need information in other places other than the root level of your component. Since you don't know if the component will change in the future, just don't use useselector at all

Comment: @Yonatan Nir - This is incorrect. You can use the state wherever you like. Whenever the store state is changed the component rerenders. When the component rerenders, useSelector runs again, and gives you the updated data, later to be used wherever you want.

Comment: @deckele that's a good point that no one else mentioned yet. If you can add an answer with that information and an example of using useDispatch inside a callback, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @Yonatan Nir already did, see my more detailed answer with an example use case down below.

Comment: @deckele so please just add to the answer what you wrote about the rerendering with the updated data from the store

Comment: @Yonatan Nir good suggestion, I updated my answer with the rerendering mechanism.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Redux store state can be read and changed from anywhere in the component, including callbacks. Whenever the store state is changed the component rerenders. When the component rerenders, useSelector runs again, and gives you the updated data, later to be used wherever you want. Here is an example of that and a usage of `useDispatch` inside a callback (after an assignment in the root level):

```
function Modal({ children }) {
  const isOpen = useSelector(state => state.isOpen);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function handleModalToggeled() {
    // using updated data from store state in a callback
    if(isOpen) {
      // writing to state, leading to a rerender
      dispatch({type: "CLOSE_MODAL"});
      return;
    }
    // writing to state, leading to a rerender
    dispatch({type: "OPEN_MODAL"});
  }
  // using updated data from store state in render
  return (isOpen ? (
      <div>
        {children}
        <button onClick={handleModalToggeled}>close modal</button>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <button onClick={handleModalToggeled}>open modal</button>
    );
  );
}
```

There is nothing you can do with mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps that you can't do with the useSelector and useDispatch hooks as well.

With that said, there are a couple of differences between the two methods that are worth considering:

1. Decoupling: with `mapStateToProps`, container logic (the way store data is injected into the component) is separate from the view logic (component rendering).
   `useSelector` represents a new and different way of thinking about connected components, arguing that the decoupling is more important between components and that components are self contained. Which is better? Verdict: no clear winner. [source](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/07/blogged-answers-thoughts-on-hooks/)
2. DX (Developer experience): using the `connect` function usually means there should be another additional container component for each connected component, where using the `useSelector` and useDispatch hooks is quite straightforward. Verdict: hooks have better DX.
3. "Stale props" and "Zombie child": there are some weird edge cases with useSelector, if it depends on props, where `useSelector` can run before the newest updated props come in. These are mostly rare and avoidable edge cases, but they had been already worked out in the older `connect` version. verdict: connect is slightly more stable than hooks. [source](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#stale-props-and-zombie-children)
4. Performance optimizations: both support performance optimizations in different ways: `connect` has some advanced techniques, using merge props and other options hidden in the connect function. `useSelector` accepts a second argument - an equality function to determine if the state has changed. verdict: both are great for performance in advanced situations.
5. Types: using typescript with `connect` is a nightmare. I remember myself feverishly writing three props interfaces for each connected component (OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps). Redux hooks support types in a rather straightforward way. verdict: types are significantly easier to work with using hooks.
6. The future of React: Hooks are the future of react. This may seam like an odd argument, but change to the ecosystem is right around the corner with "Concurrent mode" and "Server components". While class components will still be supported in future React versions, new features may rely solely on hooks. This change will of course also affect third party libraries in the eco system, such as React-Redux. verdict: hooks are more future proof.

TL;DR - Final verdict: each method has its merits. `connect` is more mature, has less potential for weird bugs and edge cases, and has better separation of concerns. Hooks are easier to read and write, as they are collocated near the place where they are used (all in one self contained component). Also, they are easier to use with TypeScript. Finally, they will easily be upgradable for future react versions.

Comment: In theory you could write your "connector" as a regular functional component that uses react-redux hooks, and simply renders your decoupled presentational component with the correct props

Answer (score 8):

I think you misunderstand what "top level" is. It merely means that, inside a functional component, `useSelector()` cannot be placed inside loops, conditions and nested functions. It doesn't have anything to do with root component or components structure

```
// bad
const MyComponent = () => {
  if (condition) {
    // can't do this
    const data = useSelector(mySelector);
    console.log(data);
  }

  return null;
}

---

// good
const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = useSelector(mySelector);

  if (condition) {
    console.log(data); // using data in condition
  }

  return null;
}
```

If anything, `mapStateToPtops` is located at even higher level than a hook call

> the rules of hooks make it very hard to use that specific hook. You still need to somehow access a changing value from the state inside callbacks

To be fair you almost never have to access changing value inside a callback. I can't remember last time I needed that. Usually if your callback needs the latest state, you are better off just dispatching an action and then handler for that action (redux-thunk, redux-saga, redux-observable etc) will itself access the latest state

This is just specifics of hooks in general (not just useSelector) and there are tons of ways to go around it if you really want to, for example

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = useSelector(mySelector);
  const latestData = useRef()
  latestData.current = data

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(latestData.current) // always refers to latest data
        }, 5000)
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

> What are the benefits of using the hook besides saving lines of code compared to mapStateToProps?

1. You save time by not writing connect function any time you need to access store, and removing it when you no longer need to access store. No endless wrappers in react devtools
2. You have clear distinction and no conflicts between props coming from connect, props coming from parent and props injected by wrappers from 3rd party libraries
3. Sometimes you (or fellow developers you work with) would choose unclear names for props in `mapStateToProps` and you will have to scroll all the way to `mapStateToProps` in the file to find out which selector is used for this specific prop. This is not the case with hooks where selectors and variables with data they return are coupled on the same line
4. By using hooks you get general advantages of hooks, the biggest of which is being able couple together and reuse related stateful logic in multiple components
5. With `mapStateToProps` you usually have to deal with `mapDispatchToProps` which is even more cumbersome and easier to get lost in, especially reading someone else's code (object form? function form? bindActionCreators?). Prop coming from `mapDispatchToProps` can have same name as it's action creator but different signature because it was overridden in `mapDispatchToprops`. If you use one action creator in a number of components and then rename that action creator, these components will keep using old name coming from props. Object form easily breaks if you have a dependency cycle and also you have to deal with shadowing variable names

.

```
import { getUsers } from 'actions/user'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    // shadowed variable getUsers, now you either rename it
    // or call it like this.props.getUsers
    // or change import to asterisk, and neither option is good
    const { getUsers } = this.props
    // ...
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUsers,
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: I don't know when was a time where I did not need to access data inside a callback. A button is pressed and you need to change the data in redux happens all the time

Answer (score 2):

*See EDIT 2 at the end for the final answer*

Since no one knows how to answer, it seems like the best answer is that you should NOT be using useselector when you need information in other places other than the root level of your component. Since you don't know if the component will change in the future, just don't use useselector at all.

If someone has a better answer than this, I'll change the accepted answer.

Edit: Some answers were added, but they just emphasize why you shouldn't be using useselector at all, until the day when the rules of hooks will change, and you'll be able to use it in a callback as well. That being said, if you don't want to use it in a callback, it could be a good solution for you.

EDIT 2: An answer with examples of all that I wanted was added and showed how `useSelector` and `useDispatch` are easier to use.

Comment: I do not get you. You can use useSelector anywhere. If you would use useSelector in the parent component, and pass the state as props to the child component. Then you are using it wrong. You can jsut hook up useSelector any any component u using.

Comment: Rules of hooks says you must use it at the root of your component, meaning you CANT use it anywhere. one of the most basic thing to do is using a callback with logic based on a value from the store. Same thing for dispatch where you want to save a value to the store from a callback. If you can't use them in a callback, they worth nothing

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. You are saying that hooks can be used in root level only, meaning hooks should not be conditional. I thought you meant hooks can only be used in parent component

Comment: This "answer" could be improved by deleting it. @CodeMonkey had a fundamental misunderstanding of how hooks work, and is claiming that other correct answers are wrong. Delete it or edit it fully to remove the confusion being caused to new readers.

Comment: If you think that the accepted answer is wrong then I got news for you my friend.. seems like you might be the one who has some misunderstanding about hooks

Answer (score 2):

The redux state returned from the `useSelector` hook can be passed around anywhere else just like its done for `mapStateToProps`. Example: It can be passed to another function too. Only constraint being that the hook rules has to be followed during its declaration:

1. It has to be declared only within a functional component.
2. During declaration, it can not be inside any conditional block . Sample code below

   ```
       function test(displayText) {
          return (<div>{displayText}</div>);
       }

       export function App(props) {
           const displayReady = useSelector(state => {
           return state.readyFlag;
           });

           const displayText = useSelector(state => {
           return state.displayText;
           });

           if(displayReady) {
               return 
               (<div>
                   Outer
                   {test(displayText)}

               </div>);
           }
           else {
           return null;
           }
       }
   ```

EDIT: Since OP has asked a specific question - which is about using it within a callback, I would like to add a specific code.In summary, I do not see anything that stops us from using useSelector hook output in a callback. Please see the sample code below, its a snippet from my own code that demonstrates this particular use case.

```
export default function CustomPaginationActionsTable(props) {
//Read state with useSelector.
const searchCriteria = useSelector(state => {
  return state && state.selectedFacets;
 });

//use the read state in a callback invoked from useEffect hook.
useEffect( ()=>{
  const postParams = constructParticipantListQueryParams(searchCriteria);
  const options = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    validateStatus: () => true
  };
  var request = axios.post(PORTAL_SEARCH_LIST_ALL_PARTICIPANTS_URI, postParams, options)
      .then(function(response)
        { 
          if(response.status === HTTP_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            console.log('Accessing useSelector hook output in axios callback. Printing it '+JSON.stringify(searchCriteria));
            
          }
                    
        })          
      .catch(function(error) {
      });
}, []);
}
```

Comment: And still when you can't use it in the most basic place where you actually need it - in a callback, it's unusable in real life situations

Comment: @YonatanNir - Hope this helps. Have updated my answer for the particular use case you are interested in. Essentially, using output of `useSelector` hook works within callback functions too.

Comment: that's not (fully) what I meant. You're describing a case where you read the state at the root level like the rules of hooks say we must, and then use that value inside a callback. I'm talking about the need to sometimes read the data from redux directly in the callback. Also writing the info in the callback to redux is even a bigger issue

Answer (score 1):

For callback functions you can use the value returned from `useSelector` the same way you would use the value from `useState`.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
    // use hook to get data from redux state.
    const stateData = useSelector(state => state.data);

    // use hook to get dispatch for redux store.
    // this allows actions to be dispatched.
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // Create a non-memoized callback function using stateData.
    // This function is recreated every rerender, a change in
    // state.data in the redux store will cause a rerender.
    const callbackWithoutMemo = (event) => {
        // use state values.
        if (stateData.condition) {
            doSomething();
        }
        else {
            doSomethingElse();
        }

        // dispatch some action to the store
        // can pass data if needed.
        dispatch(someActionCreator());
    };

    // Create a memoized callback function using stateData.
    // This function is recreated whenever a value in the
    // dependency array changes (reference comparison).
    const callbackWithMemo = useCallback((event) => {
        // use state values.
        if (stateData.condition) {
            doSomething();
        }
        else {
            doSomethingElse();
        }

        // dispatch some action to the store
        // can pass data if needed.
        dispatch(someActionCreator());
    }, [stateData, doSomething, doSomethingElse]);

    // Use the callbacks.
    return (
        <>
            <div onClick={callbackWithoutMemo}>
                Click me
            </div>
            <div onClick={callbackWithMemo}>
                Click me
            </div>
        </>
    )
};
```

> Rules of hooks says you must use it at the root of your component, meaning you CANT use it anywhere.

As Max stated in his answer just means that the hook statement itself must not be dynamic / conditional. This is because the order of the base hooks (react's internal hooks: `useState`, etc) is used by the backing framework to populate the stored data each render.

The values from hooks can be used where ever you like.

While I doubt this will be close to answering your complete question, callbacks keep coming up and no examples had been posted.

Answer (score 1):

not the answer but this hook can be very helpful if you want to get decoupled nature of `mapDispatchToProps` while keeping simplicity and dev experience of hooks:

https://gist.github.com/ErAz7/1bffea05743440d6d7559afc9ed12ddc

the reason I don't mention one for `mapStatesToProps` is that `useSelector` itself is more store-logic-decoupling than `mapStatesToProps` so don't see any advantage for `mapStatesToProps`. Of course I dont mean using `useSelector` directly but instead create a wrapper on it in your store files (e.g. in reducer file) and import from there, like this:

```js
// e.g. userReducer.js
export const useUserProfile = () => useSelector(state => state.user.profile)
```