# React router dom v6 not populating ownProps in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I recently installed beta version of react-router-dom V6, because I like Outlet and object-based routes because they make my life easier. However, since I am using React-Redux, I have a problem of not being able to get URL parameters in the `mapStateToProps` function:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        campaign: selectCampaignById(state, ownProps.match.params.id),
    };
};
```

The route is defined as:

```js
const routes = useRoutes({
        path: 'admin',
        element: <DashboardLayout />,
        children: [
            { path: '/', element: <DashboardContainer /> },
            { path: 'campaign/edit/:id', element: <CampaignEdit /> },
            { path: 'campaign/create', element: <CampaignCreate /> },
            { path: 'campaign', element: <CampaignListView /> },
            ...
        ],
    });,
```

In the above example, `ownProps.match` object is undefined, while it worked with react-router-dom V5. I want to emphasise that the routes and everything else is working, EXCEPT that I cannot get `ownProps.match` populated with url parameters.

Can anyone please give a solution for this. Thank you!

Comment: Same issue here. From an app I built back in 2017 with React, this 2022 I noticed this same issue when migrated to v6 of react router dom.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the equivalent `useSelector()` of `mapStateToProps()`.

I don't have the complete source code of your project but I would remove the mapStateToProps declaration and inside your component you can do something like:

```
const { id } = useParams()

const campaign = useSelector(state => state.campaigns[id])
```

Don't forget to add the imports:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
```

[More info](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) about `useSelector()`.

[Useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66218178/1800371) regarding to the usage of `useSelector()` and `mapStateToProps()`.

Comment: Well answered. Concise and to the point.